# Facebook does not show all open graph images

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a webpage with some standard [open graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) meta tags for Facebook. My problem is that if I place a link to the page in a facebook status message it shows only 2 of 5 images. The 2. and the 3. but not the others.

My first thought was: I did something wrong so I checked the page with the [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) but there it shows all images. I waited a week now but the problem did not solve it self.

Any thoughts on this?

This bug might be related, but it also has no solution: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/107341092730662

Comment: If our page has more than 50 likes I guess you can't edit it, but I might be wrong.

Comment: The page does not even have a like button. I copy the url myself into a facebook status message.

Comment: Can you maybe post the page url so that we can check it out instead of speculating?

Comment: The bug you refer looks similar but it is not related to behavior you describe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is related to the dimensions of images you provide. The images that omitted from appearance in feed are those having ratio of sides more than 3:1.

The page you provided have 5 images (those with ratio more than 3 will not be used by Like Button):

```
250 × 67 -> ratio 3.73
250 × 186 -> ratio 1.34 (this image will work)
250 × 166 -> ratio 1.5 (this image will work)
251 × 59 -> ratio 4.25
172 × 54 -> ratio 3.18
```

There point is to avoid usage of too long or too wide images that may not be suitable for displaying in small sizes in feed.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Here is in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/): `og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph. The image must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. You may include multiple og:image tags to associate multiple images with your page.`

Comment: @PiTheNumber, yep, this is described in several places in documentation, none of them describe this as a requirement for images to be used by Like Button (which looks to me more as bug in documentation)

Answer (score 2):

I have seen conflicting information on whether the image has to be 50px x 50px, or as large as 200px x 200px.  As of today (9 Sept. 2012), it is clear to me from both experience and from FB's own documentation, that:

**the MINIMUM size of a graphic must be 200px x 200px, to be successfully used as the og:image.**

Otherwise, I believe the aspect ratio and format info have not changed from that noted by previous posters.

Answer (score 1):

I found that thiswarning occured if there is a space at the end of the desciption.